# Right pattern for mongoose temp documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I got following mongoose models: Article and Comment.
An Article holds refs to many Comments. Now i want to be able to review new (pending) Articles and Comments before they go to the Articles and Comments Collections. Therefore i have created extra collections for the pending version:

```
var PendingArticle = mongoose.model('Article', 'pendingArticles');
var PendingComment = mongoose.model('Comment',"pendingComment");
```

It all worked fine. But now when i try to populate the comments of a PendingArticle no comments are found. I assume because it's populated from the comments collection instead of the pendingComments. Do i really need seperate schemas to accomplish that?

```
PendingArticle.find().populate('comments') ...
```

Where is my mistake or what should i do? Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use "pending[**true/false**]" property that can be updated,  in your schemas,  instead of create new schemas? With this property you can decide to publish(updating to true) or remove data or ... [other logic].

Comment: The idea behind this extra table is that there can be many of those pending articles. And the frontend needs to query the article table very often. So I don't want to loose performance when querying many articles that are not needed.